# Use 2 ports with spring boot & spring integration

Tags: java, spring, port, integration

I have a Spring Boot API with Spring integration and I would like to use 2 ports:

- 9090: Spring Integration endpoint
- 8080: Spring boot controllers
  access

Is it possible ?

Thank's

Comment: there is way to open 2 ports at mean time for tomcat. But I don think it is able to route to specific api

Comment: does it make sense to separate them in two spring boot apps? You _can_ override the embedded servlet container config and make it listen on multiple ports, but you will have to add logic for routing the specific requests to whichever port you need